# AutoCompleteTextView didnt show suggestions in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, autocompletetextview

helo,
i'm trying to implement autocompletetextview in one of my fragment, but i stuck.

problem is that autocompletetextview doesnt show suggestion. i can read adapter from textview but it still doesn't work.

```
public class fragment_dodajpodroz extends Fragment {

AutoCompleteTextView myAutoComplete;
String item[]={
          "January", "February", "March", "April",
          "May", "June", "July", "August",
          "September", "October", "November", "December"};
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    String DEBUG_TAG = "BAZA DANYCH";
    Context c = getActivity().getApplicationContext();


    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dodajpodroz, container, false);

    myAutoComplete = (AutoCompleteTextView)view.findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);


      ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (c, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, item);

      myAutoComplete.setAdapter(adapter);



    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.dodajpodroz, container, false);
}
```

Comment: instead of `c` use `getActivity()`

Comment: return view instead of inflating again dodajpodroz

Comment: @pskink - your answer is great! thans :)

Comment: @tworzywohh i know, most of my answers are so...;)

Answer (score 1):

See corrected version

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        String DEBUG_TAG = "BAZA DANYCH";
        Context c = getActivity().getApplicationContext();


        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dodajpodroz, container, false);

        myAutoComplete = (AutoCompleteTextView)view.findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);


        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (c, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, item);

        myAutoComplete.setAdapter(adapter);

        return view;
    }
```

Comment: zest, would you please show me your xml layout with autocomplete. Im getting error on my project. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32287402/android-autocomplettextview-resource-not-found-resource-is-not-a-drawable

Comment: Resource is not a drawable - means you should check this line in your xml file android:popupBackground="@color/wallet_highlighted_text_holo_dark"