# android autocomplettextview Resource not found - Resource is not a drawable

Tags: android, android-fragments

This issue is driving me crazy....

Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f0100ab a=3}
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2816)
            at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
            at android.view.View.(View.java:3460)
            at android.widget.TextView.(TextView.java:791)
            at android.widget.EditText.(EditText.java:76)
            at ***android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView***.(AutoCompleteTextView.java:137)
            at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.(AutoCompleteTextView.java:133)

my xml is :

```
 <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="38dp"
                android:id="@+id/idautoCompleteProfTextView"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext"    <---**drawable**...
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="15dp"
                android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:hint="@string/hint_signin_professional"
                android:layout_below="@+id/btnAcceptSigninProf"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:dropDownVerticalOffset="5dp"
                android:dropDownWidth="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textAutoComplete|textAutoCorrect"
                android:popupBackground="@color/wallet_highlighted_text_holo_dark"/>
```

edittext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
    <corners android:radius="0dp"/>
    <stroke android:width="2dip"
            android:color="#ffffff" />
</shape>
```

Im inflating it as a fragment.

```
public class SigninProfessionalFragment extends Fragment {

    public SigninProfessionalFragment(){}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_signin_professional, container, false);
...
```

I have not code-behind regarding the autocomplete because I just want to load it in my device and check layout,etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem should be in your theme, but not the code you posted.

Comment: I figured out if I set this in my style.xml 

    <!-- Override listChoiceBackgroundIndicator. -->
    <style name="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.AutoCompleteTextView">
        <item name="listChoiceBackgroundIndicator">?android:attr/listChoiceBackgroundIndicator</item>
    </style> I got the issue fixed. do you know why ?

Comment: This information is not enough to know what happened. How is the **ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light** before change and where is it used?

Comment: In manisfest :  
        <activity
            android:name=".controller.MainDrawer"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main_drawer" >
        </activity> and in it didnt exist in styles till I made this change. Will accept answer to be refreshed with this tip. ty

Comment: Your method of fixing is not correct. Try to remove the style you added and change the theme of activity like this `<activity android:name=".controller.MainDrawer" android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" android:label="@string/title_activity_main_drawer" > </activity>`

Comment: whats the difference between set the theme in manifest and right to activity(xml) ?